# PreparedStatement: executeUpdate insert wrongly the raw

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I try the below code: once just does not work, and when make Auto incremental the primary key it works, but bring the raw doubled.
At this point I guess it' s something stupid, so if an idea, I will be grateful.

```
    try {
        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `news`( `title`, `date`, `description`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(insertSQL);

        ps.setString(1, n.getTitle());
        ps.setString(2, n.getDate());
        ps.setString(3, n.getDescription());
        if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("DB updtata!");
        }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException |SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `executeUpdate()` twice. Are you committing the transaction?

Comment: The main problem (I put the if condition) is acually the 'SSL verifyServerCertificate property', which  rejects the connection, (for the momment I put "useSSL=false" to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in try catch block..

```
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO `news`( `title`, `date`, `description`) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(insertSQL);
    ps.setString(1, n.getTitle());
    ps.setString(2, n.getDate());
    ps.setString(3, n.getDescription());

    int rs = ps.executeUpdate();


    if (rs > 0) {

        System.out.println("DB updated!");

    }
```